# how to take headers automatically from a csv file

Tags: python, string, pandas, header

my code is going through a user input file if it's a csv or a txt to find the number of words found but I need to provide a fixed header for it such in my case : sentences, is there a way to go through this and pic up the column name automatically from the file so it wont be a fixed name maybe another file have it written data rather than sentences

```
wdata=pd.read_csv(fileinput)
nowt=wdata['sentences'].str.split().map(len).sum()
```

csv examples

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one column first specify new column name by `names` parameter and then skip original csv header by `skiprows` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
wdata=pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['col name'], skiprows=1)
```

If there is no csv header:

```
wdata=pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['col name'])
```

After some discussion is possible distinguish between column name (no space there) and in data always at least one space, so general solution is:

```
header = pd.read_csv(file, nrows=0).columns[0] 
skip = int(header.count(' ') == 0) 
df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['col'], skiprows=skip)
```

Comment: the thing is I'm trying to get the input file from the user which should be one column but it could have header randomly named and it could have no header.

Comment: and they wont be seeing the code to edit the column name inside the code

Comment: @programmingfreak - So there is sometimes csv header and sometimes no header? Is possible distinguish it?

Comment: sometimes there is no header, your code works if there is a header what if there is no header, is there a way to solve that issue ?

Comment: @programmingfreak then you have to find that describe distinguish between Header or no header

Comment: @DishinHGoyani any easy way to do that ?

Comment: @programmingfreak - It depends of data, is possible distinguish it some way?

Comment: @programmingfreak - Because if string csv header and strings data then use like no header by `wdata=pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['col name'])`, but then get first row with csv header if exist. And need some rule depends of data how distinguish it and then remove

Comment: @programmingfreak - One idea - Is possible say column name has no space and data has at least one space?

Comment: it is possible yea maybe the header contains 2 words with space between them, it's user generated one so any header or no header is expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205650/discussion-between-jezrael-and-programming-freak).